# MySQL 5.6.24: Foreign key gives ERROR 1452 (23000) error

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am facing a weird issue. It's complicated so bear with me for while.

I have 3 tables with following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `org_tbl` (
  `OrgID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`OrgID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `grp_tbl` (
  `GroupID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FkOrgID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`GroupID`,`FkOrgID`),
  KEY `fk_grp_tbl_FkOrgID_org_tbl_OrgID` (`FkOrgID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_grp_tbl_FkOrgID_org_tbl_OrgID` FOREIGN KEY (`FkOrgID`) REFERENCES `org_tbl` (`OrgID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `parent_child_grp` (
  `ChildGroupID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `GroupID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FkOrgID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ChildGroupID`,`GroupID`),
  KEY `fk_cg_ChildGroupID_FkOrgID_pg_GroupID_FkOrgID` (`ChildGroupID`,`FkOrgID`),
  KEY `fk_cg_GroupID_FkOrgID_pg_GroupID_FkOrgID` (`GroupID`,`FkOrgID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_cg_ChildGroupID_FkOrgID_pg_GroupID_FkOrgID` FOREIGN KEY (`ChildGroupID`, `FkOrgID`) REFERENCES `grp_tbl` (`GroupID`, `FkOrgID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_cg_GroupID_FkOrgID_pg_GroupID_FkOrgID` FOREIGN KEY (`GroupID`, `FkOrgID`) REFERENCES `grp_tbl` (`GroupID`, `FkOrgID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Now if following is the dataset:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM org_tbl;

OrgID       Title
2           b
3           a

mysql> SELECT * FROM grp_tbl;

GroupID     FkOrgID     Title
1           3           pg_a
2           3           pg_b

mysql> SELECT * FROM parent_child_grp;

ChildGroupID    GroupID     FkOrgID     Title
1               1           3           cg_a
2               1           3           cg_b
```

Then when I try to update value of OrgID in org_tbl with:

```
UPDATE org_tbl SET OrgID = 1 WHERE OrgID = 3;
```

I get following error:

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`parent_child_grp`, CONSTRAINT `fk_cg_GroupID_FkOrgID_pg_GroupID_FkOrgID` FOREIGN KEY (`GroupID`, `FkOrgID`) REFERENCES `grp_tbl` (`GroupID`, `FkOrgID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPD)
```

So what happens in above schema is

1. parent_child_grp (ChildGroupID, FkOrgID) => grp_tbl (GroupID, FkOrgID)
2. parent_child_grp (GroupID, FkOrgID) => grp_tbl (GroupID, FkOrgID)

If I remove the second foreign key constraint [i.e. parent_child_grp (GroupID, FkOrgID) => grp_tbl (GroupID, FkOrgID) ], then everything works fine.

**NOTE: All table have foreign keys with:

```
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Now I am not able to understand why this is happening.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to update `OrgID` value to 1, `grp_tbl` table's and `parent_child_grp` table's `FkOrgID`  column still contains the value 3.

Since `FkOrgID` is a Foreign Key depending on `OrgID`, this update will cause the `FkOrgID` column to have value the `3` which is not a value in `OrgID`.
**This violates the FK condition**.

That is why you are getting this error

Comment: But I have "ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE" on all the foreign keys

So that should take care of changing the value in those tables